# Windows 11: prevent everything except administrator account access to D drive?

Tags: windows, security, permissions, user-accounts

I am trying to protect my system after I have experienced being compromised.

So I made a local account which is standard user. I want to use this account for my work and restrict it's access to the D drive. So even if my standard account is compromised, they won't have read/write/modify/x access to my D drive.

How do you do this? I tried setting "Authenticated users" permissions in file explorer to deny access to a file to test it out. But that also prevented my administrator account (the first account signed up with microsoft email) from accessing it.

Would this really prevent a average malicious infiltrator from accessing D drive or can they easily remove this?

I see three roles on my D:/ drive file explorer permissions: Authenticated Users, System, Administrators.

Comment: You can use the security properties of the drive / folder to allow it to Administrators and not to anyone else.

Comment: @John so I just edit and remove SYSTEM and Authenticated users? And it doesn't lock out my windows adminstrator account (the first account) from accessing it?

Comment: That is what you wanted: Everyone except Administrators.

Comment: @John Yes, everything denied access to D drive except the Administrator Account. Had to make sure to not lock myself out of accessing D drive with the admin account. I have f-ed up things on my OS before.

Comment: @J.Reku if you have administrator access, you can't really lock yourself out because you can always make yourself owner if you are administrator, and once you are owner, you can modify the security settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting security permissions is the way to go.

Keep in mind that rights are propagated as follows:

- If deny permissions are set, they always apply first. Deny a group, everyone in that group is denied even if there are other rights that give access.
- If no user or group is specified that the user belongs to, then the user is denied.
- If the user is directly mentioned or a group it is in is mentioned, then those rights apply.

This means that you will want to remove all existing rights from the object, and give the group Administrators full access permissions.

Its also a good idea to give the group SYSTEM full access permissions. This will ensure that programs with services installed to the D share have access and programs such as virusscanners and backup software can also do its thing.

Next, ensure that the current user is not owner, but change this to administrators too.

Lastly, set the checkbox to automatically apply these rights to all child objects.

Comment: @J.Reku AFAIK, users cannot be added to the `System` group, as it's not how that works. While users can execute a program with `System` permissions via [`PsExec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) [`-s`], it requires Admin privs to do so.

Comment: @JW0914 you are correct, because SYSTEM is not a group but a user.

Answer (score 0):

There are many elevation of privilege attacks each year, so an attacker could gain administrative privileges and will be able to access d:

So protection by NTFS permissions is ok, but encrypting d: as well would be even better.
An attacker cannot crack the encryption password unless its short/dictionary. If the attacker installs a software keylogger, he could grab that password, too, yes, so you could even go so far and apply encryption that uses a certificate (SmartCard). But that would go too far. If the data is truly important, use it on a different system and not on one that you don't trust.